# On a theoretical platform

Tags: grammar

Please tell me what is meant by the bold part

***On a theoretical platform of shared historiography***, the regions in Indian history acquire a new significance in the 750-1200 period.
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=aVd9xS4yo04C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false
Thank you.

Comment: This is better asked on our sister site (ELL); we'll move it over there for you. Short story is someone has advanced a new and fecund theory involving India sharing some of its history (with who isn't said in this short excerpt, but possibly a foreign nation), which can serve as the basis or foundation for future development along the same lines (i.e. is a *platform* which can give rise to much more than the original theory).

Comment: @DanBron Whichever way I squint at that quote, I can't squeeze that reading out of it ...

Comment: @Araucaria Meh, seems the plain surface reading to me, but I didn't bother to read the larger context. I could be wrong, but the place to determine that is ELL, not ELU. Though I did overlook the word *regions*, which I've now noticed, which at the very least indicates the new theory primarily involves internal rather than external politics.

Comment: @DanBron Historiography does not mean *history*  though.

Comment: @Araucaria Better then to explain what you took away from the passage? I can also delete my comment, if you prefer.

Comment: @DanBron I can't work it out exactly. I would wonder whether the author understood what historiography is, but they are apparently a historian so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historiography is the study of the **writing** of history, rather than the history itself, and how our view of history changes over time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historiography

My guess as to the meaning of "On a theoretical platform of shared historiography" would be thus:

"shared historiography" presumably refers to the different regions' historiographies, or the way each region writes it's own history and perhaps that of the country as a whole.  Some of this historiography may differ between regions, and some will be the same.  Perhaps "shared" refers to the portions of the historiographies which are the same between different regions, or perhaps it refers to all the different historiographies, viewed as a whole.

The "platform" may refer to the viewpoint where one looks down on all the historiographies and can see the differences and shared aspects.  This viewpoint doesn't exist literally (it's an abstract academic concept), so it's theoretical in that sense.

Also, because historiography is a relatively new academic discipline, it may be that nobody has ever actually looked at the historiographies for all Indian regions before, and so it's also theoretical in that sense: it doesn't even exist as an academic study.  Having said that, that paragraph implies that the study *has* been done, and is described in the linked-to book.

Comment: Hmm that still doesn't fit with the meaning of the sentence as a whole. (your explanation of *historiography* is spot on though!)

Comment: What doesn't fit?  It seems to make perfect sense to me:  it's saying (In my interpretation) that when you look at the writing of history across all the regions, you notice some new things ("new significance") in the 750-1200 period.

Comment: But the subject of *acquire a new significance* is not the period 750-1200. The subject of *acquire a new significance* is *the regions in Indian history*. (scratches head)

Comment: Are you sure?  Why mention that time period, then?

Comment: I don't know! I don't understand the sentence!! : /

Comment: What don't you understand about **my interpretation of it**?

Comment: Ah, I've just had a look at [the blurb for this book on Amazon](http://www.amazon.in/Interpreting-Medieval-India-Vol-1/dp/0230637612). Assuming the author wrote it, I think their literary ornateness exceeds their English language proficiency.

Comment: I don't understand how your interpretation of it matches up with the grammar of the sentence or the meaning of its individual parts. (but that is probably just a shortcoming of mine. It's still true though, that I do not understand!)

Comment: "a theoretical platform of shared historiography" is a noun in this context, so it's like saying **"When we stand on this "thing", these other "things" acquire a new significance in the 750-1200 period". **

Comment: Yes, right. So' On NP1, NP2 acquire a new significance in the 750-1200 period'. NP2 there is "the regions in Indian history". So doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I suspect that what the author is announcing is a historiographical perspective which supersedes existing histories of individual petty kingdoms in favor of synchronous examination of entire regions of the subcontinent.